# (python,dash) Global variable does not change when background=True is set in the python dash callback

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I created a simple code that changes the value of a class static variable when a button is pressed using python dash.
And I want to set the running property by processing background=True in this callback function.
However, if background=True is set here, I have confirmed that value of Global.test in the code below does not change.
The update_clicks function first sets the value of Global.test to 5.
And btn_test outputs the changed Global.test value.
Since Global.test has been changed to 5, I expected 5 to be output in btn_test, but None is output. And if I delete background=True, Global.test in btn_test outputs 5 normally. Is there any way to change the value of Global.test while keeping the background=True property?

below is my all code.

```
import os
import dash
from dash import DiskcacheManager, CeleryManager, Input, Output, html
from Global import *

class Global():
    test = None

if 'REDIS_URL' in os.environ:
    # Use Redis & Celery if REDIS_URL set as an env variable
    from celery import Celery
    celery_app = Celery(__name__, broker=os.environ['REDIS_URL'], backend=os.environ['REDIS_URL'])
    background_callback_manager = CeleryManager(celery_app)

else:
    # Diskcache for non-production apps when developing locally
    import diskcache
    cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")
    background_callback_manager = DiskcacheManager(cache)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, background_callback_manager=background_callback_manager)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div([html.P(id="paragraph_id", children=["Button not clicked"])]),
        html.Button(id="button_id", children="Run Job!"),
        html.Button(id="button_test", children="Test Job!"),
        html.Div('test', id='div_test')
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    output=Output("paragraph_id", "children"),
    inputs=Input("button_id", "n_clicks"),
    background=True,
    running=[
        (Output("button_id", "disabled"), True, False),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True 
)
def update_clicks(n_clicks):
    Global.test = 5
    print('Run : ' + str(Global.test))    
    return [f"Clicked {n_clicks} times"]


@app.callback(
    Output('div_test', 'children'),
    Input('button_test', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True 
)
def btn_test(n):    
    print('test : ' + str(Global.test))
    return Global.test

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening here is explained by the following excerpt from the documentation:

> When Dash apps run across multiple workers, their memory is not shared. This means that if you modify a global variable in one callback, that modification will not be applied to the other workers / processes.

The documentation says the following on storing shared data:

> To share data safely across multiple processes or servers, we need to store the data somewhere that is accessible to each of the processes.
>
> There are three places you can store this data:
>
> In the user's browser session, using dcc.Store
>
> On the disk (e.g. in a file or database)
>
> In server-side memory (RAM) shared across processes and servers such as a Redis database. Dash Enterprise includes onboard, one-click Redis databases for this purpose.

https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks

In your case I'd recommend going for the `dcc.Store` option.

Example based on code in question:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("paragraph_id", "children"),
    Output("store", "data"),
    Input("button_id", "n_clicks"),
    background=True,
    running=[
        (Output("button_id", "disabled"), True, False),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_clicks(n_clicks):
    return f"Clicked {n_clicks} times", 5

@app.callback(
    Output('div_test', 'children'),
    Input('button_test', 'n_clicks'),
    State("store", "data"),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def btn_test(n, store):
    return store
```